# Getting the file path of a uploaded file on the users disk in IE/Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, firefox, asp.net-mvc-3

For a website I am working on, I need to allow users to be able to specify the path to a file on a network drive, so I simply tried using a file field and having javascript get the value, however because of browser security I cannot get this path.

Is there anyway to get around this browser security and allow users to browse to the file on the network drive and select it to specify the path?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Sorry the last sentence confused me. You want someone to upload a file, and during the upload keep track of where that file was on the user's computer? And then what...?

Comment: No sorry, should have stated more clearly. Im looking to just get the file path, Im not actually submitting the file to the server just the file path. But im getting hung up on browser security because it generates a fake path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this is impossible with javascript. Flash also forbids from accessing the client file paths. ActiveX could be used but it will work only in IE and must be installed on the client computer.